# Postgres get values by giving more priority to a certain column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pgsql table with data as below.

```
platform;party;code;value
----------------------------
Global;null;name;abc
Local;null;name;abc
Global;null;number;123
Global;null;email;def
Global;Jen;email;fhg
Global;Jack;email;ijk
```

How to write a query where for a party & platform value passed, it need's to fetch values that the party has & the platform values which the party doesn't have as code params, and if null is passed for party, it should fetch all records where platform value is given by user.

(a) i.e. if i pass party as 'Jen' and platform as 'Global' From the above records i should get the following as result:-

```
platform;party;code;value
----------------------------
Global;null;name;abc
Global;null;number;123
Global;Jen;email;fhg
```

(b) and if i pass 'Jack' and platform as 'Global' it should return :-

```
platform;party;code;value
----------------------------
Global;null;name;abc
Global;null;number;123
Global;Jack;email;ijk
```

(c) if only platform is passed as 'Global' is passed then it should return :-

```
platform;party;code;value
----------------------------
Global;null;name;abc
Global;null;number;123
Global;null;email;def
```

(d) if only platform is passed as 'Local' is passed then it should return :-

```
platform;party;code;value
----------------------------
Local;null;name;abc
```

P.S.- I am sorry for my bad english. Will edit with proper language soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (platform, (party is not null), code) t.*
from t
where platform = ? and
      (party = ? or party is null)
order by platform, (party is not null) desc, code;
```

This puts the non-`NULL` rows before the `NULL` rows.

Comment: I tried :- "select distinct on ( platform,party, code) e.* from test e
where platform = 'GLOBAL' and (party = 'Jack' or party is null) 
order by platform, (party is not null ) desc, code;"

But getting the following error ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
LINE 1: select distinct on (party, platform, code) t.* from test t, with an arrow pointing at code

Comment: @N29 . . . I fixed that.

Comment: thank you so much.. My knowledge in sql is a little weak. I am working on improving it